# Component cannot subscribe to event that is triggered from another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service. The communication provides via the service. I provide service in a common module. But UserProfileComponent cannot subscribe to the event.

here are the codes

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        public dialogService: DialogService,
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private userService: UserService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.userService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
            debugger
            this.message = message;
        });
    }
}


export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private userService: UserService,
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        public dialogService: DialogService,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,

    ) { }
    onFileChanged(event: any) {
        this.userService.changeMessage('Hello from Sibling')
    }
}

export class UserService {

    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

    changeMessage(message: string) {
        this.messageSource.next(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the components `constructor` in your post?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because there are two instances of your service. If you have lazy-loaded modules then separate injector is created for lazy-loaded module. You need to properly manage your service so that multiple instances are not possible.

Best way is to create a CoreModule which only contains services and include this module only in your root app module. Services initialised in root app module is available all modules. Moreover you can initialise this coreModule such that it can only be initialised once and throws error on any new initialisation.

Go through this: https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a
This is really good article about it.

To block multiple instances of your service, you can modify service constructor as:

```
export class MyService{
    ...
    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() service: MyService){
        if(service){
            throw new Error("Multiple Instances");
        }
    }

}
```